# Pages Export to PDF changes layout

Tags: pdf, pages

I am using Pages. I have a 255 page document, which includes text and photographs.
I intend to export the document as a pdf when completed. Attempts to export drafts of the document, in all three "grades", good, better, best, result in photographs mis-located, and text or even complete pages missing altogether. The photographs that are misplaced are located exactly where other photographs should be, and repeated attempts result in different photographs or text being misplaced or relocated.

Comment: Which version of Pages & macOS do you have?

Comment: Have you tried making several docs ie 1 per chapter so each is 15 pages or 25 pages? As this may be a memory issue...

Comment: two things… 1) What does it look like if you open it with Preview? 2) what does it look like if you go to Print, then save that as PDF, rather than directly Exporting?